# React Reflux - Generator using Yeoman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I am trying to generate a react reflux project using the yeoman generator but I am getting following error. I am using yeoman generator for this and I have installed generator-react-reflux via npm.

```
pdc1-4s6zyr1:expProj administrator$ yo
? 'Allo administrator! What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
  Run a generator
❯ Angular 
  Webapp 
  React Reflux 
  Karma 
  Yeogurt 
  Mocha 
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:86
? 'Allo administrator! What would you like to do? React Reflux

Make sure you are in the directory you want to scaffold into.
This generator can also be run with: yo react-reflux



     _-----_
    |       |    .---------------------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |        Bye from us! Chat soon.        |
   `---------´   |                                       |
    ( _´U`_ )    |            The Yeoman Team            |
    /___A___\    | https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman#team |
     |  ~  |     '---------------------------------------'
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9379
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-react-reflux/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:445:21)
    at composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:568:15)
    at yoyo._initGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/yoyo.js:100:8)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/yoyo.js:407:35)
    at PromptUI.onCompletion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:69:10)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.completed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1965:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1902:14)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.completed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9397:23)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1902:14)
    at AnonymousObserver._onCompleted (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:3032:49)
```

My Node and NPM are updated

```
pdc1-4s6zyr1:expProj administrator$ npm -v
2.5.1
pdc1-4s6zyr1:expProj administrator$ node -v
v0.12.0
```

My Yeoman's version is

```
pdc1-f3t18r1:~ administrator$ yo -v
1.3.3
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong in generating the project?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but try again with a recent version.